# Is Doomfist invulnerable while targeting his ultimate, Meteor Strike?

Tags: overwatch

When you activate Doomfist's ultimate ability, Meteor Strike, you jump up into the sky, enter a targeting view for a few seconds, then smash back down.

[image]

While you're targeting the ability, your character is *very* high up — perhaps even above the usual height limit of the map. It would be hard to an enemy to target you in that brief time, but a skilled sniper might be able to pull it off.  Would it be possible for them to save their team?

Is Doomfist invulnerable when he's in the sky targeting his ability? Can you stop the ultimate by killing him at that point? What about using an interrupting ability such as Ana's Sleep Dart?

Comment: My current understanding is that he is invulnerable during his ult, however considering that he is also invisible for the duration, hitting him with a skill like sleep-dart is pretty much impossible and it would take a very skilled widow/hanzo to deal with him.

Comment: I'd also be curious to know if he's invulnerable not just when he's targeting and seemingly off the map, but also in the split second after he jumps up and the split second before he lands.

Comment: Don't know if it is a bug, but apparently a friendly ana can still heal him while he is ulting [as seen here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/6ltyxf/ana_can_heal_an_ulting_doomfist_in_the_high_skies/).

Comment: While this question is technically on-topic, I think it's a little early for us to be able to definitely answer this.  There's going to be a lot of changes made to Doomfist between now (what amounts to a beta period) and when he's released in something closer to a finalized version, and this could be something that changes..

Answer (score 3):

Doomfist is invulnerable while casting his ultimate BUT can be hit with friendly bullets:

You can't kill him, but you can heal him.

Comment: Probably good to wait till he's released. It just looks so buggy that you can heal him, I wouldn't be surprised if they fix that.

Answer (score -2):

So I did a [bit](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20757576376) [of](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/5stb8a/doomfist_ultimate_and_kit/) [reading](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20757636395) as well as played a couple of games and I have come to the following conclusion:

Firstly, and most obviously, he is invisible, so that makes it quite a lot harder to hit him with any kind of attack, especially abilities like Sleeping Dart.

Secondly, he is **outside** the map while ulting, meaning he is quite literally invulnerable as projectiles can't actually travel there. I have found no conclusive proof of this, but considering many other people claim it (without ever citing sources), and the fact that I never managed to damage Doomfist in his ult no matter how hard I tried and what I threw at him (even tried Pharah ult once), I believe this to be true.

However, I would not guarantee that it stays this way: Blizzard will possibly change him/his mechanics in the near future, but currently this seems to be the state of affairs.

Comment: Doomfist can be healed during his ultimate, so he's likely still inside the map. ([See Иво Недев's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/312784/181240))